# Define a context in tomcat server.xml in openshift

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, server.xml

I want to define a context in my tomcat server on openshift cloud. I have done it successfully in my local tomcat server but I don't know how to do it on openshift.
I did it in local by adding :

```
<Context docBase="E:/captcha" path="/test/captcha"></Context>
```

to my tomcat's server.xml file. But in openshift I don't know how to define the docbase attribute.
Thanks for any useful response!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be using `<Context>` in server.xml these days.

Instead, put your WAR file in the proper place. If you must use an XML descriptor, take the `META-INF/context.xml` file (which you *should* have!) and put it into `CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml` and Tomcat will deploy it.

Unfortunately, if you can't use WAR-deployment, then you'll still have to figure out what the `docBase` should be. Where is your WAR file?

Comment: I don't want o deploy a war file. I want to define a storage for my files in server.xml . and it should be addressed in openshift system.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of PaaS that you don't have to worry about the configuration of the application server? Just produce a WAR file and deploy? Anyhow, whether it's a WAR file or an exploded WAR directory (like `E:/captcha`), the point is the same: don't edit `conf/server.xml` and add `<Context>` elements. There are better ways to do it.